# Getting False with my Def, What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python

```
def richNumber(n):
    nb = []
    n = int(n)
    sum1 = 0
    for i in range(n, n+1):
        if n % i ==0:
            nb.append(i)
    sum1 = sum(nb) - nb[-1]
    if sum1 > n:
        return True
    else:
        return False

n = int(input("n:"))

print(richNumber(n))
```

I have 5 Test Cases:

```
n = 4
n = 12
n = 6
n = 20
n = 100
```

With n = 4 and 6 the output is false ,with n = 12,20,100 is supposed to be true but its showing false.

This function used to get all divisor of n in a list, if the sum of all divisor of n (not N) is larger than N is true, smaller is False

Comment: You probably need to tell us what your function is supposed to do...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, got that for you!

Comment: What did you intend `for i in(n, n+1)` to mean?

Comment: oh yeah, i copied the old code. my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current richNumber function will always return False because sum1 will
always be 0. Try the following code:

```
def richNumber(n):
    nb = []
    n = int(n)
    sum1 = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            nb.append(i)
    sum1 = sum(nb)
    if sum1 > n:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in (n, n+1)
```

Iterates over two numbers, `n` and `n + 1`, not all divisors. You need to use `range` to iterate from `1` to `n`

```
for i in range(1, n + 1)
```

Comment: @FilipMüller No, it doesn't. `for i in tuple` (or any other iterable) iterates over all the elements in the tuple.